# Why is my play-pause-button moving when i press the play-previous or play-next button (HTML, CSS, JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to figure out why the play-pause-button keeps moving up and to the left when i press the play-previous or ply-next buttons , it remains perfectly still when i press the play-pause-button alone , but soon as pressing the previous or next buttons , it jumps up to the left side of the button div, i'm not sure if this is being cause by the javascript or css? any ideas ? This player was taken from: https://codepen.io/himalayasingh/pen/QZKqOX

[image of player with play-pause-button moved up after pressing play-next](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CstgL.png)

music.html

```
<div id="app-cover">
                <div id="bg-artwork"></div>
                <div id="bg-layer"></div>
                <div id="player">
                  <div id="player-track">
                    <div id="album-name"></div>
                    <div id="track-name"></div>
                    <div id="track-time">
                      <div id="current-time"></div>
                      <div id="track-length"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="s-area">
                      <div id="ins-time"></div>
                      <div id="s-hover"></div>
                      <div id="seek-bar"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="player-content">
                    <div id="album-art">
                      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/img/_1.jpg" class="active" id="_1">
                      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/img/_2.jpg" id="_2">
                      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/img/_3.jpg" id="_3">
                      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/img/_4.jpg" id="_4">
                      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/img/_5.jpg" id="_5">
                      <div id="buffer-box">Buffering ...</div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="player-controls">
                      <div class="control">
                        <div class="button" id="play-previous">
                          <i class="fas fa-backward"></i>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="control">
                        <div class="button" id="play-pause-button">
                          <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="control">
                        <div class="button" id="play-next">
                          <i class="fas fa-forward"></i>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
```

music.js

```
<script>
    $(function()
{
    var playerTrack = $("#player-track"), bgArtwork = $('#bg-artwork'), bgArtworkUrl, albumName = $('#album-name'), trackName = $('#track-name'), albumArt = $('#album-art'), sArea = $('#s-area'), seekBar = $('#seek-bar'), trackTime = $('#track-time'), insTime = $('#ins-time'), sHover = $('#s-hover'), playPauseButton = $("#play-pause-button"),  i = playPauseButton.find('i'), tProgress = $('#current-time'), tTime = $('#track-length'), seekT, seekLoc, seekBarPos, cM, ctMinutes, ctSeconds, curMinutes, curSeconds, durMinutes, durSeconds, playProgress, bTime, nTime = 0, buffInterval = null, tFlag = false, albums = ['Dawn','Me & You','Electro Boy','Home','Proxy (Original Mix)'], trackNames = ['Skylike - Dawn','Alex Skrindo - Me & You','Kaaze - Electro Boy','Jordan Schor - Home','Martin Garrix - Proxy'], albumArtworks = ['_1','_2','_3','_4','_5'], trackUrl = ['https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/music/2.mp3','https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/music/1.mp3','https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/music/3.mp3','https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/music/4.mp3','https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/music/5.mp3'], playPreviousTrackButton = $('#play-previous'), playNextTrackButton = $('#play-next'), currIndex = -1;

    function playPause()
    {
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            if(audio.paused)
            {
                playerTrack.addClass('active');
                albumArt.addClass('active');
                checkBuffering();
                i.attr('class','fas fa-pause');
                audio.play();
            }
            else
            {
                playerTrack.removeClass('active');
                albumArt.removeClass('active');
                clearInterval(buffInterval);
                albumArt.removeClass('buffering');
                i.attr('class','fas fa-play');
                audio.pause();
            }
        },300);
    }

        
    function showHover(event)
    {
        seekBarPos = sArea.offset(); 
        seekT = event.clientX - seekBarPos.left;
        seekLoc = audio.duration * (seekT / sArea.outerWidth());
        
        sHover.width(seekT);
        
        cM = seekLoc / 60;
        
        ctMinutes = Math.floor(cM);
        ctSeconds = Math.floor(seekLoc - ctMinutes * 60);
        
        if( (ctMinutes < 0) || (ctSeconds < 0) )
            return;
        
        if( (ctMinutes < 0) || (ctSeconds < 0) )
            return;
        
        if(ctMinutes < 10)
            ctMinutes = '0'+ctMinutes;
        if(ctSeconds < 10)
            ctSeconds = '0'+ctSeconds;
        
        if( isNaN(ctMinutes) || isNaN(ctSeconds) )
            insTime.text('--:--');
        else
            insTime.text(ctMinutes+':'+ctSeconds);
            
        insTime.css({'left':seekT,'margin-left':'-21px'}).fadeIn(0);
        
    }

    function hideHover()
    {
        sHover.width(0);
        insTime.text('00:00').css({'left':'0px','margin-left':'0px'}).fadeOut(0);       
    }
    
    function playFromClickedPos()
    {
        audio.currentTime = seekLoc;
        seekBar.width(seekT);
        hideHover();
    }

    function updateCurrTime()
    {
        nTime = new Date();
        nTime = nTime.getTime();

        if( !tFlag )
        {
            tFlag = true;
            trackTime.addClass('active');
        }

        curMinutes = Math.floor(audio.currentTime / 60);
        curSeconds = Math.floor(audio.currentTime - curMinutes * 60);
        
        durMinutes = Math.floor(audio.duration / 60);
        durSeconds = Math.floor(audio.duration - durMinutes * 60);
        
        playProgress = (audio.currentTime / audio.duration) * 100;
        
        if(curMinutes < 10)
            curMinutes = '0'+curMinutes;
        if(curSeconds < 10)
            curSeconds = '0'+curSeconds;
        
        if(durMinutes < 10)
            durMinutes = '0'+durMinutes;
        if(durSeconds < 10)
            durSeconds = '0'+durSeconds;
        
        if( isNaN(curMinutes) || isNaN(curSeconds) )
            tProgress.text('00:00');
        else
            tProgress.text(curMinutes+':'+curSeconds);
        
        if( isNaN(durMinutes) || isNaN(durSeconds) )
            tTime.text('00:00');
        else
            tTime.text(durMinutes+':'+durSeconds);
        
        if( isNaN(curMinutes) || isNaN(curSeconds) || isNaN(durMinutes) || isNaN(durSeconds) )
            trackTime.removeClass('active');
        else
            trackTime.addClass('active');

        
        seekBar.width(playProgress+'%');
        
        if( playProgress == 100 )
        {
            i.attr('class','fa fa-play');
            seekBar.width(0);
            tProgress.text('00:00');
            albumArt.removeClass('buffering').removeClass('active');
            clearInterval(buffInterval);
        }
    }
    
    function checkBuffering()
    {
        clearInterval(buffInterval);
        buffInterval = setInterval(function()
        { 
            if( (nTime == 0) || (bTime - nTime) > 1000  )
                albumArt.addClass('buffering');
            else
                albumArt.removeClass('buffering');

            bTime = new Date();
            bTime = bTime.getTime();

        },100);
    }

    function selectTrack(flag)
    {
        if( flag == 0 || flag == 1 )
            ++currIndex;
        else
            --currIndex;

        if( (currIndex > -1) && (currIndex < albumArtworks.length) )
        {
            if( flag == 0 )
                i.attr('class','fa fa-play');
            else
            {
                albumArt.removeClass('buffering');
                i.attr('class','fa fa-pause');
            }

            seekBar.width(0);
            trackTime.removeClass('active');
            tProgress.text('00:00');
            tTime.text('00:00');

            currAlbum = albums[currIndex];
            currTrackName = trackNames[currIndex];
            currArtwork = albumArtworks[currIndex];

            audio.src = trackUrl[currIndex];
            
            nTime = 0;
            bTime = new Date();
            bTime = bTime.getTime();

            if(flag != 0)
            {
                audio.play();
                playerTrack.addClass('active');
                albumArt.addClass('active');
            
                clearInterval(buffInterval);
                checkBuffering();
            }

            albumName.text(currAlbum);
            trackName.text(currTrackName);
            albumArt.find('img.active').removeClass('active');
            $('#'+currArtwork).addClass('active');
            
            bgArtworkUrl = $('#'+currArtwork).attr('src');

            bgArtwork.css({'background-image':'url('+bgArtworkUrl+')'});
        }
        else
        {
            if( flag == 0 || flag == 1 )
                --currIndex;
            else
                ++currIndex;
        }
    }

    function initPlayer()
    {   
        audio = new Audio();

        selectTrack(0);
        
        audio.loop = false;
        
        playPauseButton.on('click',playPause);
        
        sArea.mousemove(function(event){ showHover(event); });
        
        sArea.mouseout(hideHover);
        
        sArea.on('click',playFromClickedPos);
        
        $(audio).on('timeupdate',updateCurrTime);

        playPreviousTrackButton.on('click',function(){ selectTrack(-1);} );
        playNextTrackButton.on('click',function(){ selectTrack(1);});
    }
    
    initPlayer();
});
</script>
```

custom.css

```
#app-cover  
{
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 430px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: -4px auto;
}


#player
{
    position: relative;
    height: 105%;
    z-index: 3;
}

#player-track
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    padding: 13px 22px 10px 184px;
    background-color: #829aa3;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
    transition: 0.9s ease top;
    z-index: 1;
}

#player-track.active
{
    top: -100px;
}

#album-name
{
    color: #54576f;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#track-name
{
    color: #acaebd;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 2px 0 13px 0;
}

#track-time
{
    height: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#current-time
{
    float: left;
}

#track-length
{
    float: right;
}

#current-time, #track-length
{
    color: transparent;
    font-size: 11px;
    background-color: #ffe8ee;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: 0.3s ease all;
}

#track-time.active #current-time, #track-time.active #track-length
{
    color: #f86d92;
    background-color: transparent;
}

#s-area, #seek-bar
{
    position: relative;
    height: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#s-area
{
    background-color:#ffe8ee;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#ins-time
{
    position: absolute;
    top: -29px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    white-space: pre;
    padding: 5px 6px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display:none;
}

#s-hover
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.2;
    z-index: 2;
}

#ins-time, #s-hover
{
    background-color: #3b3d50;
}

#seek-bar
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    background-color: #fd6d94;
    transition: 0.2s ease width;
    z-index: 1;
}

#player-content
{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(6, 21, 29);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #989797;
    border-radius: 15px;
    z-index: 2;
}

#album-art
{
    position: absolute;
    top: -40px;
    width: 115px;
    height: 115px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    transform: rotateZ(0);
    transition: 0.3s ease all;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#album-art.active
{
    top: -60px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #fff7f7, 0 30px 50px -15px #afb7c1;
}

#album-art:before
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: -10px auto 0 auto;
    background-color: #d6dee7;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #fff;
    z-index: 2;
}

#album-art img
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

#album-art img.active
{
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
}

#album-art.active img.active
{
    z-index: 1;
    animation: rotateAlbumArt 3s linear 0s infinite forwards;
}

@keyframes rotateAlbumArt
{
    0%{ transform: rotateZ(0); }
    100%{ transform: rotateZ(360deg); }
}

#buffer-box
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 13px;
    color: #1f1f1f;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 6px;
    margin: -12px auto 0 auto;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.19);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

#album-art img, #buffer-box
{
    transition: 0.1s linear all;
}

#album-art.buffering img
{
    opacity: 0.25;
}

#album-art.buffering img.active
{
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: blur(2px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
}

#album-art.buffering #buffer-box
{
    opacity: 1;
}

#player-controls
{
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 5px 0 141px;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.control
{
    width: 33.333%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}

.button
{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 25px;
    left: 15px;
    top: 25px;
    background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
#play-pause-button i {
    position: absolute;
}

.button i
{
    display: block;
    color: #d6dee7;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    right: 14px;
    line-height: 0;
}

.button, .button i
{
    transition: 0.2s ease all;
}

.button:hover i
{
    color: rgb(84, 247, 163);
}

#ytd-url {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  margin: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ae5f87;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(174, 95, 135, 0.86);
  z-index: 125;
}
```

Comment: the link seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: I didn't see any mistake. Could you please show us a video/gif of what it looks like to you?

Comment: @dandavis I guess this link is the original and OP is trying to change it to his needs. Tried to put his stuff into a fiddle, but the buttons are not showing up https://jsfiddle.net/0mugdafL/

Comment: I've added an image of what happens when pressing play-next or play-previous button , any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove extra css `right: 14px; line-height: 0` for `.button i` style. It is causing the issue.

```
.button i
{
    display: block;
    color: #d6dee7;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    /*right: 14px;           //Remove this line
    line-height: 0;*/        //Remove this line
}
```

```js
$(function()
{
    var playerTrack = $("#player-track"), bgArtwork = $('#bg-artwork'), bgArtworkUrl, albumName = $('#album-name'), trackName = $('#track-name'), albumArt = $('#album-art'), sArea = $('#s-area'), seekBar = $('#seek-bar'), trackTime = $('#track-time'), insTime = $('#ins-time'), sHover = $('#s-hover'), playPauseButton = $("#play-pause-button"),  i = playPauseButton.find('i'), tProgress = $('#current-time'), tTime = $('#track-length'), seekT, seekLoc, seekBarPos, cM, ctMinutes, ctSeconds, curMinutes, curSeconds, durMinutes, durSeconds, playProgress, bTime, nTime = 0, buffInterval = null, tFlag = false, albums = ['Dawn','Me & You','Electro Boy','Home','Proxy (Original Mix)'], trackNames = ['Skylike - Dawn','Alex Skrindo - Me & You','Kaaze - Electro Boy','Jordan Schor - Home','Martin Garrix - Proxy'], albumArtworks = ['_1','_2','_3','_4','_5'], trackUrl = ['https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/music/2.mp3','https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/music/1.mp3','https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/music/3.mp3','https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/music/4.mp3','https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/music/5.mp3'], playPreviousTrackButton = $('#play-previous'), playNextTrackButton = $('#play-next'), currIndex = -1;

    function playPause()
    {
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            if(audio.paused)
            {
                playerTrack.addClass('active');
                albumArt.addClass('active');
                checkBuffering();
                i.attr('class','fas fa-pause');
                audio.play();
            }
            else
            {
                playerTrack.removeClass('active');
                albumArt.removeClass('active');
                clearInterval(buffInterval);
                albumArt.removeClass('buffering');
                i.attr('class','fas fa-play');
                audio.pause();
            }
        },300);
    }

        
    function showHover(event)
    {
        seekBarPos = sArea.offset(); 
        seekT = event.clientX - seekBarPos.left;
        seekLoc = audio.duration * (seekT / sArea.outerWidth());
        
        sHover.width(seekT);
        
        cM = seekLoc / 60;
        
        ctMinutes = Math.floor(cM);
        ctSeconds = Math.floor(seekLoc - ctMinutes * 60);
        
        if( (ctMinutes < 0) || (ctSeconds < 0) )
            return;
        
        if( (ctMinutes < 0) || (ctSeconds < 0) )
            return;
        
        if(ctMinutes < 10)
            ctMinutes = '0'+ctMinutes;
        if(ctSeconds < 10)
            ctSeconds = '0'+ctSeconds;
        
        if( isNaN(ctMinutes) || isNaN(ctSeconds) )
            insTime.text('--:--');
        else
            insTime.text(ctMinutes+':'+ctSeconds);
            
        insTime.css({'left':seekT,'margin-left':'-21px'}).fadeIn(0);
        
    }

    function hideHover()
    {
        sHover.width(0);
        insTime.text('00:00').css({'left':'0px','margin-left':'0px'}).fadeOut(0);       
    }
    
    function playFromClickedPos()
    {
        audio.currentTime = seekLoc;
        seekBar.width(seekT);
        hideHover();
    }

    function updateCurrTime()
    {
        nTime = new Date();
        nTime = nTime.getTime();

        if( !tFlag )
        {
            tFlag = true;
            trackTime.addClass('active');
        }

        curMinutes = Math.floor(audio.currentTime / 60);
        curSeconds = Math.floor(audio.currentTime - curMinutes * 60);
        
        durMinutes = Math.floor(audio.duration / 60);
        durSeconds = Math.floor(audio.duration - durMinutes * 60);
        
        playProgress = (audio.currentTime / audio.duration) * 100;
        
        if(curMinutes < 10)
            curMinutes = '0'+curMinutes;
        if(curSeconds < 10)
            curSeconds = '0'+curSeconds;
        
        if(durMinutes < 10)
            durMinutes = '0'+durMinutes;
        if(durSeconds < 10)
            durSeconds = '0'+durSeconds;
        
        if( isNaN(curMinutes) || isNaN(curSeconds) )
            tProgress.text('00:00');
        else
            tProgress.text(curMinutes+':'+curSeconds);
        
        if( isNaN(durMinutes) || isNaN(durSeconds) )
            tTime.text('00:00');
        else
            tTime.text(durMinutes+':'+durSeconds);
        
        if( isNaN(curMinutes) || isNaN(curSeconds) || isNaN(durMinutes) || isNaN(durSeconds) )
            trackTime.removeClass('active');
        else
            trackTime.addClass('active');

        
        seekBar.width(playProgress+'%');
        
        if( playProgress == 100 )
        {
            i.attr('class','fa fa-play');
            seekBar.width(0);
            tProgress.text('00:00');
            albumArt.removeClass('buffering').removeClass('active');
            clearInterval(buffInterval);
        }
    }
    
    function checkBuffering()
    {
        clearInterval(buffInterval);
        buffInterval = setInterval(function()
        { 
            if( (nTime == 0) || (bTime - nTime) > 1000  )
                albumArt.addClass('buffering');
            else
                albumArt.removeClass('buffering');

            bTime = new Date();
            bTime = bTime.getTime();

        },100);
    }

    function selectTrack(flag)
    {
        if( flag == 0 || flag == 1 )
            ++currIndex;
        else
            --currIndex;

        if( (currIndex > -1) && (currIndex < albumArtworks.length) )
        {
            if( flag == 0 )
                i.attr('class','fa fa-play');
            else
            {
                albumArt.removeClass('buffering');
                i.attr('class','fa fa-pause');
            }

            seekBar.width(0);
            trackTime.removeClass('active');
            tProgress.text('00:00');
            tTime.text('00:00');

            currAlbum = albums[currIndex];
            currTrackName = trackNames[currIndex];
            currArtwork = albumArtworks[currIndex];

            audio.src = trackUrl[currIndex];
            
            nTime = 0;
            bTime = new Date();
            bTime = bTime.getTime();

            if(flag != 0)
            {
                audio.play();
                playerTrack.addClass('active');
                albumArt.addClass('active');
            
                clearInterval(buffInterval);
                checkBuffering();
            }

            albumName.text(currAlbum);
            trackName.text(currTrackName);
            albumArt.find('img.active').removeClass('active');
            $('#'+currArtwork).addClass('active');
            
            bgArtworkUrl = $('#'+currArtwork).attr('src');

            bgArtwork.css({'background-image':'url('+bgArtworkUrl+')'});
        }
        else
        {
            if( flag == 0 || flag == 1 )
                --currIndex;
            else
                ++currIndex;
        }
    }

    function initPlayer()
    {   
        audio = new Audio();

        selectTrack(0);
        
        audio.loop = false;
        
        playPauseButton.on('click',playPause);
        
        sArea.mousemove(function(event){ showHover(event); });
        
        sArea.mouseout(hideHover);
        
        sArea.on('click',playFromClickedPos);
        
        $(audio).on('timeupdate',updateCurrTime);

        playPreviousTrackButton.on('click',function(){ selectTrack(-1);} );
        playNextTrackButton.on('click',function(){ selectTrack(1);});
    }
    
    initPlayer();
});
```

```css
#app-cover  
{
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 430px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: -4px auto;
}


#player
{
    position: relative;
    height: 105%;
    z-index: 3;
}

#player-track
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    padding: 13px 22px 10px 184px;
    background-color: #829aa3;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
    transition: 0.9s ease top;
    z-index: 1;
}

#player-track.active
{
    top: -100px;
}

#album-name
{
    color: #54576f;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#track-name
{
    color: #acaebd;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 2px 0 13px 0;
}

#track-time
{
    height: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#current-time
{
    float: left;
}

#track-length
{
    float: right;
}

#current-time, #track-length
{
    color: transparent;
    font-size: 11px;
    background-color: #ffe8ee;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: 0.3s ease all;
}

#track-time.active #current-time, #track-time.active #track-length
{
    color: #f86d92;
    background-color: transparent;
}

#s-area, #seek-bar
{
    position: relative;
    height: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#s-area
{
    background-color:#ffe8ee;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#ins-time
{
    position: absolute;
    top: -29px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    white-space: pre;
    padding: 5px 6px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display:none;
}

#s-hover
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.2;
    z-index: 2;
}

#ins-time, #s-hover
{
    background-color: #3b3d50;
}

#seek-bar
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    background-color: #fd6d94;
    transition: 0.2s ease width;
    z-index: 1;
}

#player-content
{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(6, 21, 29);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #989797;
    border-radius: 15px;
    z-index: 2;
}

#album-art
{
    position: absolute;
    top: -40px;
    width: 115px;
    height: 115px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    transform: rotateZ(0);
    transition: 0.3s ease all;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#album-art.active
{
    top: -60px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #fff7f7, 0 30px 50px -15px #afb7c1;
}

#album-art:before
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: -10px auto 0 auto;
    background-color: #d6dee7;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #fff;
    z-index: 2;
}

#album-art img
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

#album-art img.active
{
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
}

#album-art.active img.active
{
    z-index: 1;
    animation: rotateAlbumArt 3s linear 0s infinite forwards;
}

@keyframes rotateAlbumArt
{
    0%{ transform: rotateZ(0); }
    100%{ transform: rotateZ(360deg); }
}

#buffer-box
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 13px;
    color: #1f1f1f;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 6px;
    margin: -12px auto 0 auto;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.19);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

#album-art img, #buffer-box
{
    transition: 0.1s linear all;
}

#album-art.buffering img
{
    opacity: 0.25;
}

#album-art.buffering img.active
{
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: blur(2px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
}

#album-art.buffering #buffer-box
{
    opacity: 1;
}

#player-controls
{
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 5px 0 141px;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.control
{
    width: 33.333%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}

.button
{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 25px;
    left: 15px;
    top: 25px;
    background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
#play-pause-button i {
    position: absolute;
}

.button i
{
    display: block;
    color: #d6dee7;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    /*right: 14px;*/            /*Remove this line*/
    /*line-height: 0;*/         /*Remove this line*/
}

.button, .button i
{
    transition: 0.2s ease all;
}

.button:hover i
{
    color: rgb(84, 247, 163);
}

#ytd-url {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  margin: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ae5f87;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(174, 95, 135, 0.86);
  z-index: 125;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app-cover">
                <div id="bg-artwork"></div>
                <div id="bg-layer"></div>
                <div id="player">
                  <div id="player-track">
                    <div id="album-name"></div>
                    <div id="track-name"></div>
                    <div id="track-time">
                      <div id="current-time"></div>
                      <div id="track-length"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="s-area">
                      <div id="ins-time"></div>
                      <div id="s-hover"></div>
                      <div id="seek-bar"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="player-content">
                    <div id="album-art">
                      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/img/_1.jpg" class="active" id="_1">
                      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/img/_2.jpg" id="_2">
                      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/img/_3.jpg" id="_3">
                      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/img/_4.jpg" id="_4">
                      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/img/_5.jpg" id="_5">
                      <div id="buffer-box">Buffering ...</div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="player-controls">
                      <div class="control">
                        <div class="button" id="play-previous">
                          <i class="fas fa-backward"></i>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="control">
                        <div class="button" id="play-pause-button">
                          <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="control">
                        <div class="button" id="play-next">
                          <i class="fas fa-forward"></i>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
```

You can test it [here](https://codepen.io/nimittshah/pen/XWNKvVq) also

Comment: unfortunately that didn't fix the issue , it's only the play-pause-button which jumps up everytime i press the play-next or previous buttons and then it jumps back down to its original position when i press the play button twice ? i thought it might be  js issue , on your test link it seems to work fine , but not on my app ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the fault , it was another css class ".fa" that was being used for another element on the page, it kept changing the music play button , my css class was not specific enough. Need to remember specificity is the key in css!